# Will passing Input() arguments to a dynamic component ever lag behind the view rendering?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I currently have a list view in my application, and whenever a user clicks a list item I inject a new component below it which creates a view/edit window. My dynamic component creation looks like so:

```
private alertViewEditFactory(cRef: ViewContainerRef, alert: Alert, mode: number): ComponentRef<AlertViewEditComponent> {
    const ref = cRef.createComponent(this.factory);

    // what if the component tries to render the view before this is reached?
    ref.instance.mode = mode;
    ref.instance.alert = alert;
    ref.instance.service = this.userService;

    return ref;
}
```

where `mode`, `alert`, and `service` are all `@Input()`s.

**Question**: Will setting the input arguments *after* component creation ever cause an issue where the view renders *before* the arguments are set? Although I've never seen this happen yet, I wonder if there is a safer solution to creating the component and at the same time setting the input arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The component **won't try to project the Inputs into DOM** together with all angular expressions present in the template until you call `detectChanges()` on the component ref's change detector, so in your case like that `ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, which will in turn cause init, content init and view init and respective checks to be made (more on lifecycle [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)).

So far, you only called `createComponent`, which **merely instantiates** your component and **renders bare markup** (without the evaluated angular expressions) to its parent view container (more on that [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef)), so the only thing you should refrain from is counting on having the inputs initialized by the time the constructor is called.

So no, there shouldn't be any issue with that dynamic component creation. You actually don't have any choice, Angular's component lifecycle always creates the instance, renders bare markup and only after that evaluates the template expressions together with those inputs if they are somehow used in the template.